# Adding more than two image to the canvas in android

Tags: android

i am new to android and trying to merge three image into the canvas.as u will see in my code using three image.but in the canvas only two image is showing the first one and the last one,seems like that the middle image(desert) is lost while drawing in the canvas.here is the code

code:-

```
package com.example.combineimage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IInterface;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CombineActivity extends Activity {

    private Bitmap image1,image2,image3,combo_image,image1newsize,image2newsize,image3newsize,merge_image;
    Context mcontext;
    private InputStream inputis1,inputis2,inputis3;
    private Button click_to_combine;
    private final int fixedimage_size=100;
    private ImageView final_imageview;
    int blurValue = 5;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> myimage_list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_combine);
        mcontext=CombineActivity.this;

        click_to_combine=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_click);

        final_imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        myimage_list=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        try{
            inputis1=mcontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.koala);
        image1=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputis1);
        image1newsize=resize_image(image1);
        inputis2=mcontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.desert);
         image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputis2);
         image2newsize=resize_image(image2);
         inputis3 =mcontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.jellyfish);
         image3=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputis3);
         image3newsize=resize_image(image3);

         myimage_list.add(image1newsize);
         myimage_list.add(image2newsize);
         myimage_list.add(image3newsize);
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                inputis2.close();
                inputis2.close();
                inputis3.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        click_to_combine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                merge_image=merge_given_image(myimage_list);

                final_imageview.setImageBitmap(merge_image);
            }
        });

    }

    protected Bitmap merge_given_image(ArrayList<Bitmap> myimage_list2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rect srcrect,destrect;
        Bitmap combobitmap;
        int total_width=0,total_height=0;
        int total_image=myimage_list2.size();
        int count=0;
        Canvas mcanvas;
        Bitmap temp_bitmap=null;
        for(int i=0;i<total_image;i++)
        {
             temp_bitmap=myimage_list2.get(i);
            total_width=total_width+temp_bitmap.getWidth();
            Log.e("Total size", ".."+total_width+total_image);

        }
        total_height=temp_bitmap.getHeight();
        Log.e("Total size", ".."+total_height);
        combobitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(total_width, total_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mcanvas=new Canvas(combobitmap);

        for(int i=0;i<total_image;i++)
        {
            srcrect=new Rect(0, 0, myimage_list2.get(i).getWidth(), myimage_list2.get(i).getHeight());
            destrect=new Rect(srcrect);
            if(i!=0)
            {
                destrect.offset(myimage_list2.get(i-1).getWidth(), 0);

                count=count+1;
                Log.e("COUNT", ".."+count);
            }

            mcanvas.drawBitmap(myimage_list2.get(i), srcrect, destrect, null);

        }

        return combobitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap resize_image(Bitmap image_org) {


        int org_width=image_org.getWidth();
        int org_height=image_org.getHeight();

        int newheight=fixedimage_size;
        int newwidth=fixedimage_size;

        float scalewidth=((float)newwidth)/org_width;
        float scaleheight=((float)newheight)/org_height;

        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();

        matrix.postScale(scalewidth, scaleheight);

        Bitmap newsizeimage=Bitmap.createBitmap(image_org, 0, 0, org_width, org_height, matrix, true);

        return newsizeimage;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    protected Bitmap merge_given_image(Bitmap image_first, Bitmap image_second,
            Bitmap image_third) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Bitmap combobitmap;
        //BlurMaskFilter blurfilter;
        //Paint paintblur=new Paint();

        int total_width,total_height;


        total_width=image_first.getWidth()+image_second.getWidth()+image_third.getWidth();
        total_height=image_first.getHeight();


        combobitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(total_width, total_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas combocanvas=new Canvas(combobitmap);


//      //Create background in White
//       Bitmap alpha = combobitmap.extractAlpha();
//       paintblur.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//       combocanvas.drawBitmap(combobitmap, 0, 0, paintblur);

//      //Create outer blur, in White
//       blurfilter = new BlurMaskFilter(blurValue, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER);
//       paintblur.setMaskFilter(blurfilter);
//       combocanvas.drawBitmap(combobitmap, 0, 0, paintblur);

//      //Create inner blur
//       blurfilter = new BlurMaskFilter(blurValue, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.INNER);
//       paintblur.setMaskFilter(blurfilter);
//       combocanvas.drawBitmap(combobitmap, 0, 0, paintblur);


        combocanvas.drawBitmap(image_first,0f, 0f, null);
        combocanvas.drawBitmap(image_second, (image_first.getWidth()/2), 0f, null);
        combocanvas.drawBitmap(image_third, image_second.getWidth(), 0f, null);

        return combobitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        image1.recycle();
        image1newsize.recycle();
        image2.recycle();
        image2newsize.recycle();
        image3.recycle();
        image3newsize.recycle();
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

in the above code u will find two method one having three bitmap and one method having arraylist of those three image.so in the method with three image display half of the first two image with some modification i.e.`combocanvas.drawBitmap(image_second, (image_first.getWidth()/2), 0f, null);`but the method with arraylist shows only two image.here the snapshot for the output also [image: sanpshot of output].
i follow and go through he link are
1:[merging image with rect draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151727/create-alpha-gradient-on-image-to-create-fade-effect)
2:[merging image in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416456/how-to-add-3-images-in-a-canvas-in-android)

but not getting the desired output so can anybody tell  me where i m doing wrong.any help will be very helpfull.Thanks